# Intercept SOAP response in Loadrunner

Tags: xml, soap, loadrunner, exi

A webservice returns

```
<SOAP: Envelope>
<SOAP: Header>
    <SOAP: Body>
        <RootElement>
        <![CDATA[Base64 encoded string]]>
        </RootElement>
    </SOAP : Body>
</SOAP: Header>
```

Base64 encoded string is actually an EXI encoded XML. I know how to decode base 64, then convert EXI to XML. Lets call that MyEXIEncoder.class (Java class)
However, we currently have a lot of Loadrunner test cases that are based on the XML responses (they dynamically use the values in the payloads to pass to the subsequent requests)

I need a means to Intercept the SOAP response from my test step, use my custom class that does the decode and return the response back so that subsequent steps can work in the existing scripts.

Any help wold be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is DFE (Data Format Extensions).
Some information about it can be found in the product documentation (or just open

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/HPE/LoadRunner/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/c_web_data_format_extensions.htm
```

Note that we provide Base64 DFE in the product but you will need to implement your own EXI to XML converter via a new DFE. An example of how to make one is here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\HPE\LoadRunner\samples\DataFormatExtension
```

Also some useful information can be found here:

https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/LoadRunner-Practitioners-Forum/LoadRunner-Support-Tip-Custom-DFE-Data-Format-Extension/td-p/566596

If the file mentioned in the post is not available in your version it can be found here - https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.50/help/WebHelp/Content/_TopNav_contentPDFs.htm?Highlight=creating%20custom%20DFE

Comment: Thank you @Buzzy. I am not able to access the help file. I downlowded the compiled htmls, but when I open them, I can see only the left hand side contents tree. Right hand side pane is blank. Please can you point me to alternate source?

Comment: You should be able to download from the following links:https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.50/bin/DFE_developer_guide.chm

Comment: I will try to get those files added to the blog post

Comment: The files are in the blog post now (in the comments) - https://community.softwaregrp.com/dcvta86296/attachments/dcvta86296/sws-LoadRunner_SF/22878/1/dfe_guides.zip

Comment: Thanks @Buzzy. I am out of my depth here. I have passed this information to my team. I will respond as soon as I hear from them.